# Javascript callback function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, raphael

I am using this function to store animation functions and call it one by one for sequential animation.

I am not sure what I am missing in the below code. I wanted it to be a callback function.

currently this method runs only once.

```
function treasure(){

    var blinky = function ()
    {
        if (funqueue.length > 0)
        {
            ((funqueue.shift())(), blinky);
        }
        else { return }

    }
     blinky();

}
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

If it's intended as a callback, it should be passed within the calling parenthesis rather than after. (Also, the extra, wrapping parenthesis aren't really necessary.)

```
funqueue.shift()(blinky);
```

As is, `blinky` is just the 2nd value for the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) and nothing happens with it.

And, if it's not a callback, but rather just needs to be called after each function in `funqueue`, then just:

```
funqueue.shift();
blinky();
```

Comment: I changed it to as you described above but still it is calling only once. Is there a way blinky can be called again and again. So that I can run my animation I stored in Funqueue until the queue gets empty.

Comment: @Ajax3.14 Do the functions in `funqueue` accept and call a callback? Something like: `function (callback) { ...; callback(); }`. If not, then just call `blinky` directly. See my edit.